# How do I remove special characters from GET submit

Tags: php, html, post, get, sanitize

I am having an issue with special characters with a web script that I have that executes a command to send a username to my game server to reward them for voting.

`<form action="index.php" method="GET">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>`

It submits to the database with the correct information special characters and all - but when executed to my gameserver it negates the special characters and they can abuse it by using the name Testusername/ or Testusername// and receive multiple rewards daily.

I have tried using hidden types but my system cannot work with POST.

Any ideas? I'm helpless.

EDIT ***

Any 0-9 _ a-z characters are allowed special characters being !@#$%^&*()_+[}{} etc. I am using escape strings and I am not worried about sql injection I tried multiple ways of sanitizing and they all failed. I am using mySQL but not for the sending of the reward it is there as a log and to verify users that haven't voted in the last 24 hours and prevent them from doing it again. Basically putting it plain they vote with the username Test and get their reward and vote with the username Test/ and it says Test voted again ingame and the receive x2 the rewards

Comment: What do you mean by special characters? Like... accents? UTF-8? Or characters such as * & ^ $ ! @ # ) ( { } [ ] and so on? You really need to be careful with allowing special characters inside your database. Make sure to use php's built in functions to protect your SQL from injection. [mysqli_escape_string()](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-escape-string.php)
[stripslashes()](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) We really need much more information to help you. From the general overview you've given us, the problem is with the logic itself. If you are using MySQ

Comment: Do you know which characters and sequences are allowed on the remote server? To be precise you'll have to match it exactly. You might need to whitelist allowed characters rather than remove specific ones. The source of the data (GET/POST) is irrelevant. Would be helpful to know more about: *"when executed to my gameserver it negates the special characters"*

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T15IkJhVpvg Interesting Filter tutorial, FYI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple `preg_replace` should do it:

```
$username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9_]#', '', $username);
```

This strips everything but:

- Lowercase alpha characters
- Digits 0 through 9
- underscore

If uppercase is OK, then add `A-Z` to the regex, or perhaps `strtolower()` the input beforehand. Do this before you save the input or send it to the other server.

I'm a little unsure of your exact dilemma with the game server, but ideally, you should get a response from the other server to see what username was actually entered before you save it, and you wouldn't have to filter it at all because you would have the filtered value from the other server.

Comment: Is the first argument a regular expression? If so, cool. I was unaware it took regexp as an arg.

Comment: Yes that's correct: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php *preg_replace — Perform a regular expression search and replace*

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.. Just populate the bad_chars array with all the bad chars...

```
array $bad_chars = array('@', '!', '#'); // setup your chars to filter out

for($i = 0; $i < size_of($bad_chars); $i++) // iterate through them all
{
     str_replace($bad_chars[i], '', $_GET['string_to_be_filtered']); // replace all
}
```

Comment: The only problem I see with this is that there are *loads* of "special characters" to account for.

Comment: Yeah thanks I already tried this - the issue with this was <button value="Link 1" onClick="javascript:load (1);window.open('<?echo $site_link[1];?>');"  and I am unable to click these windows to open the voting websites now that I use this filter. - It doesn't open the windows.

Comment: @Wes, I agree. But at some time, somewhere, he has to define the list of bad chars right?

Comment: @user152... Then don't run the url variable through the filter.

Comment: @user1529625: That sounds like a completely unrelated issue. Brant: Another alternative is to declare the characters that are OK to use explicitly, which I imagine would be a much smaller pool.

Comment: And just realized I declared an array type before the variable name, not necessary in php. My bad. Sometimes syntax gets crossed up between languages... oops.

Answer (score 0):

As you only want to replace the slash, you could use this.

```
<?php 
$user = $_GET["user"];
$user = str_replace("/", "", $user);
?>
```

This is a more efficient version of an other post, before me:

```
<?php 
$user = $_GET["user"];
$special = array('@', '!', '#'); 
$user = str_replace($special, "", $user);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace following to covert special characters

```
$formdesc = htmlentities($_POST['formdesc'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Hope this will helpful to you